# Why do I need App Registartion in Azure and how do they relate to my App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

I've done some reading in regards to Azure AD, but I still can't wrap my head around it. The confusion might be there also because of how my company tries to standarize how a azure project should look like.

Imagine I have two things: SPA app (served by App Service) and API (on this App Service, ASP.NET). The approach that the company is suggesting is that both of those should have their App Registrations.

Now, I'd like the API to have access to Ms Graph. In order to do that, looking at other projects, I updated my AppRegistration to request for Ms Graph roles, Admin gave consent, and in API I used [ConfidentialClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-initializing-client-applications) to reuse my Client Id/Secret to get token and then access MsGraph.

Why the hustle? Why not just use Managed Identity of my API and [grant needed permissions using New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell%2Cprogramming-language-csharp#grant-access-to-microsoft-graph)?

Why do I need App Registration here? Do I need both? Should I access Ms Graph using my App Registration and confidential client in my API? How does my App Service relate to my App Registration in code?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a step back and define a few things that will make things easy to understand:

**Your app service:** this is just a compute environment, just as Azure Functions, Logic apps or VMs. This is where your code executes.

**Azure AD App registration:** this is an identity that you can use in your code to identify your service and get access to resources you need. The Azure AD app registration has several capabilities:

- build an app in one tenant and used in multiple tenants (multi-tenant app)
- consent framework, allowing you to request permissions and the owner to grant it
- define roles and permissions, so that you can configure who is allowed to call your API
- 3-legged OAuth flows which allows you to act on behalf of the user
- confidential client flows which allow the app to act on its own (like a service account)

**Azure Managed Identities:** this is also an identity that you can use to identify your service and get access to resources you need. It only has a subset of the capabilities of Azure AD app.

- confidential client flow which allows the identity to act on its own (like a service account)
- credentials managed for you by the platform

Depending on what you are trying to do, you can use one or the other identity: rarely if ever you will need both.

In your case, you need an identity to act on its own. So either app registration or managed identity will work. Your API may benefit from using an app registration if you want to define roles and permissions. The primary advantage of using an app registration in your scenario is that the consent model is simpler to use and understand. The disadvantage is that you need to manage credentials for the app. This pro/con is reversed when using a managed identity.

Comment: I think that since my API is rather backend-for-frontend and is not intended to be accessed by other APIs or SPAs then I don't actually need AppRegistration for it and I just need the SPA AppRegistration. This allows me to have Azure AD single sign on and I can expect JWT token on API side to have scope of the SPA app. Does it sound good? I also understand that if I need roles in my app (and by app I mean here SPA+API) then I can do them in AppRegistartion of SPA and API will look again in the JWT passed from SPA

Comment: How do you plan to restrict that only your frontend is able to access your backend? What stops anyone from getting a token for your SPA and calling your backend directly? One option is to make the API an app registration, create a role and require "user assignment", and assign your SPA to that role. That way you avoid anyone else calling the API. Of course there maybe other considerations here that I am not aware of: so just providing another option if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need both at a time. These are two ways to get the access of MS graph for your API. They are used for different purpose.

**Managed Identity (Using System Identity)**

· Use the Managed Identity if you don’t require your API to be authenticate from any provider.

·  A managed identity from Azure Active Directory allows App Service to access resources through role-based access control (RBAC), without requiring app credentials

[image]

· It known as safe way to give your web app access to data is to use a [system-assigned managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

· Currently, there's no option to assign any permissions(MS graph) through the Azure portal for Managed Identity

· When we do Manged Identity of any application its show only for Enterprise application.

Reference : [Tutorial - Web app accesses Microsoft Graph as the app - Azure App Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell%2Cprogramming-language-csharp#grant-access-to-microsoft-graph)

**App Registration.**

· To set the authentication and authorization of your app from different provider its need your app registration id.

· It’s required to configure a service and get a token from the Microsoft identity platform endpoint that service can use to call Microsoft Graph under its own identity.

·In this using portal you can add permission (MS Graph) for your application.

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service